# Laravel DB insert([]) only insert first record of array

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this simple seeder class but for some reason is only inserting the first element from the array and the command is not returning any error.

Im using Laravel 5.8 and postgres as DB engine.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PermissionsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('permissions')->insert([
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'list_users',
            'display_name' => 'List users',
            'description' => 'Can list all users',
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'show_user',
            'display_name' => 'Show single user',
            'description' => 'Can show single user details',
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);  
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide an array of arrays as the first argument:

```php
DB::table('permissions')->insert([
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'list_users',
        'display_name' => 'List users',
        'description' => 'Can list all users',
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'show_user',
        'display_name' => 'Show single user',
        'description' => 'Can show single user details',
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, i forgot that!